# Intializing variable in a Mixin Class, Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
mixin CustomRepo {
  String name = '';
  // get name => na;

  void doSome() {
    print("did something");
  }
}

class ChildClass with CustomRepo {
  ChildClass();
}
```

I created a class using a mixin and I want to initialize a variable  in the mixin when the `ChildClass` is instantiated. How can I pass a value from `ChildClass(name: "Some name")` to the `name` variable in the mixin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set the variable directly:

```dart
mixin CustomRepo {
  String name = '';

  void doSome() {
    print("did something");
  }
}

class ChildClass with CustomRepo {
  ChildClass({required String name}) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```